# Spivak Calculus on manifolds, Theorem 4-8.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definition

In Michael Spivak's book, Calculus on Manifolds, in 4th Chapter theorem 8 (4-8), I am having a difficulty in making sense of the expression, $f^{*}\omega \wedge f^{*}\eta$.

Here $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ is a differentiable function.

$Df(p): \mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ is the derivative at $p$ and a linear transformation induced by this is $f_{*}: \mathbb{R}^{m}_{f(p)} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}_{p}$ such that $f_{*}(v_{p}) = (Df(p)(v))_{f(p)}$.

$f^{*}\omega(p)((v_{1})_{p},\ldots,(v_{k})_{p}) = w(f(p))(f_{*}(v_{1})_{p}),\ldots,f_{*}((v_{k})_{p}))$

$\omega$ and $\eta $ are $k$-forms on $\mathbb{R}^{m}$.

$\omega\wedge\eta(p) = \sum_{1\leq i_{1}<\ldots i_{k}\leq n} 
\sum_{1\leq j_{1}<j_{2}<\ldots < j_{l}\leq n} \omega_{i_{1}i_{2},\ldots,i_{k}}(p)\eta_{j_{1}j_{2},\ldots,j_{l}}\varphi_{i_{1}}(p)\wedge\ldots\wedge\varphi_{i_{k}}(p)\wedge\varphi_{j_{1}} (p)\wedge\ldots\wedge\varphi_{j_{l}}(p)$.

From the above two notions, I am unable to make sense of $f^{*}\omega\wedge f^{*}\eta$.

Please tell me if I need to give any more clarifications about the question.

Comment: Can you write down $f^*\omega$ in the first place?

Comment: Yes, I could write it out as written in 4th paragraph of my question. Can I write it even more 'finely'?

Comment: Ordinarily one just says that pullback of a wedge product is by definition the wedge product of the pullbacks. If you know how to pull back a basic $1$-form and you know how to calculate wedge product, then you're done. It's a horrid mess to write out, however.

Comment: The book says that it's a theorem that (which is left as an exercise to the reader) that $f^{*}(\omega\wedge\eta) = f^{*}\omega\wedge f^{*}\eta$.

Comment: About pull backs on 1-form I have to think about them for a while.

Comment: I haven't looked at Spivak's book in many decades and am used to teaching this my own ways ... So he must define $f^*\omega$ explicitly for a $k$-form $\omega$. To prove the result is either very painful bookkeeping or an induction argument, most likely.